# Why can't we create object in Qt without the new keyword (i.e. on stack)?

Tags: c++, qt

Why can't we create object in QT without the `new` keyword?  Usually we create pointer to an object, like this:

```
QLabel *ql=new QLabel();    ql->show()
```

But I want to create an object like this:

```
QLabel ql=QLabel();    ql.show()
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 22):

The thing is that the Qt controls (labels, buttons) are  in a hierarchy (buttons belong to forms, for example).  And the way Qt is implemented requires that when an object is destroyed, all objects that belong to it are destroyed as well.

If you place objects on a stack (that's how  "create without `new` keyword" is really called), they will be destroyed automatically.  That's the property of C++, and it holds for all programs.  Here's how the things would work if you allocated your label on the stack.

```
{
    QLabel ql = QLabel(some_form); 
    ql.show()
} // scope ends, ql is deleted

delete some_form;
  // ql will be deleted here as well
  // but it's already dead!
  // Program crashes!
```

Such stack allocation would mean that when you destroy the object the label belongs to, the label might already have been destroyed.  It will make your program crash.

Actually, you can *sometimes* create objects on stack.  In the `main` function, you may allocate on stack your "main control" (usually it's the main window).  The thing is that this object won't be destroyed during the program execution, so it can safely be on stack until main exits--i.e. the program terminates.  Here's a quote from [Qt tutorial](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/linguist-hellotr-main-cpp.html):

```
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QPushButton>
 #include <QTranslator>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);

     QTranslator translator;
     translator.load("hellotr_la");
     app.installTranslator(&translator);

     QPushButton hello(QPushButton::tr("Hello world!"));
     hello.resize(100, 30);

     hello.show();
     return app.exec();
 }
```

Comment: There is a brief explanation from Qt on this as well, here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/objecttrees.html

Answer (score 11):

Change

```
QLabel ql=QLabel();
```

to

```
QLabel ql;
```

and read some C++ book.

Answer (score 4):

You can create Qt objects from stack (without new) but those objects are automatically deleted when they fall out of scope. For example:

```
void doSomething()
{
    QLabel ql; 
    ql.show()
} // scope ends, ql is deleted
```

And that's how C++ works, it's not a Qt specific feature.

Answer (score 3):

```
QLabel ql;
```

creates a `QLabel` on the stack.
Note that it just lives until the current scope exits.

Comment: It's only created on the stack if this code is in a function. As a global it will be created on the heap.