# Using 'new' to declare variables without using delete afterward in Qt

Tags: qt, memory-management, memory-leaks, new-operator, delete-operator

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646300/why-cant-we-create-object-in-qt-without-the-new-keyword-i-e-on-stack/3646420), I can conclude that there're 2 main ways (there may be other ways, of course) of declaring a new widget in Qt:

1. Not using `new` keyword:

```
QLabel lb;
lb.setText("a");
```

2. Using `new` keyword:

```
QLabel *lb = new QLabel;
lb->setText("a");
```

So, in some of my tutorials, I've seen the instructor used the 2nd way, without using `delete` afterward. From what I have read from a lot of articles (for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)), when using `new` we must always use `delete` after that, to avoid memory leak.

But when reading other articles, for example [this article](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/dynamic-memory-allocation-with-new-and-delete/), they mentioned that:

> Only after your program terminates is the operating system able to
> clean up and “reclaim” all leaked memory.

In my program, sometimes I did use `delete` when I want to completely vaporize something off the table:

```
QFormLayout *destroyAffineForm = inputFieldAffineBox->findChild<QFormLayout*>("inputFieldFormBoxAffine", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
while (destroyAffineForm->count() > 0 && (child = destroyAffineForm->takeAt(0)) != nullptr)
{
    delete child->widget(); // delete the widget
    delete child;   // delete the layout item
}
delete destroyAffineForm;
```

But there're often a lot of widget that stays in place from the moment the program started, until it ended (without me calling `delete` at the end), for example a `QLabel` holding some header text.

So... all in all, will those variables (that persists through the process until the application is closed) create memory leaks and I have to insert a bunch of `delete` statement to released them, or is the OS eventually going to handle it? (I know that maybe this is a duplicated question, but I'm getting lots of mixed statements here)

P.S: Some info about my machine

- Operating on Windows 10, 64-bit
- Qt Creator 4.14.2
- Qt 5.15.2 (MSVC
  2019, 64 bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All QObjects will delete their own child objects automatically. (See docs [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject).) QWidgets are QObjects. So as long as you establish a parent/child relationship, you do not need to manually delete your objects. To do that, simply pass a pointer to the parent object to the constructor:

```
QLabel *label1 = new QLabel;   // <<- NEED TO DELETE
QLabel *label2 = new QLabel(some_parent_obj);   // Will be deleted when some_parent_obj is deleted
```

Comment: You may want to link to this: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject)

Comment: @drescherjm Good suggestion!

Comment: This may seems like a trivial question, but, for widgets created within the `.ui` file in QtCreator (not created by code), their parent is already set, so there's no need to do anything, or vice versa? (Example pic : https://ibb.co/BtyRB3b)

Comment: I don't ever use that myself, but I can't imagine that you need to delete those objects that QtCreator makes for you.