# Issue regarding setting parent of widget in Qt

Tags: qt, memory-management, memory-leaks, parent-child, new-operator

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67793467/using-new-to-declare-variables-without-using-delete-afterward-in-qt) here, in general:

> All QObjects will delete their own child objects automatically. (See
> [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject) here.) QWidgets are QObjects. So as long as you establish a
> parent/child relationship, you do not need to manually delete your
> objects. To do that, simply pass a pointer to the parent object to the
> constructor:
>
> ```
> QLabel *label1 = new QLabel;   // <<- NEED TO DELETE
> QLabel *label2 = new QLabel(some_parent_obj);   // Will be deleted when some_parent_obj is deleted
> ```

So some questions arises:

1. Does **every** widget necessary **needed/required** a parent? If no, what are the exceptions? If yes, what happens to widgets *without* parent?

I asked this because from examples in Qt Docs, some example widgets have parents ([`QLabel` example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html)) but some doesn't ([`QBarChart` example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-barchart-example.html), and also `QFont`, `QColor`, etc...).

So I'm wondering if there's an exception, **or** those widgets just don't need any parents, **or** if I declare them with `new` for some reason, I have to `delete` afterward.

And vice versa...

2. Does a widget without parent **guarantee** to cause a memory leak (or something similar) when the widget which it stays in (not necessary its parent) is deleted? Or if it's removed from a layout without any deletion happening?

Because from my experience with my code, I've created probably quite a lot (~100) of widgets and other stuffs without neither setting any parent (nor using `delete` afterward), and the project appears to run fine without any stalls even after a while (the effect might be underlying though, as I haven't run Memcheck), hence this question is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does every widget necessary needed/required a parent?

If you want them to be deleted automatically - yes. But...

> If no, what are the exceptions? If yes, what happens to widgets without parent?

You do not need to provide a parent to widget if you attach it to layout using [`QLayout::addWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addWidget). If you look into [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qlayout.cpp.html#928), you'll see that when you do so, it automatically attaches layout's parent as widget's parent(unless you didn't attach layout to any widget).

But if you leave the widget created with `new` without parent and do not attach to anything - it is leaking memory. You must delete it either using `delete` or [`QObject::deleteLater`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater). The last option is recommended when object has any connections.

> Does a widget without parent guarantee to cause a memory leak (or something similar) when the widget which it stays in (not necessary its parent) is deleted? Or if it's removed from a layout without any deletion happening?

As I already mention `QLayout::addWidget` sets parent for added widget, so the answer is no. Also note, that when you call `QLayout::removeWidget`, it removes only `QLayoutItem` from layout, but widget's parent stays the same as it was after calling `QLayout::addWidget`.

Comment: Interesting. Another question: What will happened to memory leaks? Will they be cleaned up eventually (if so, then when?) ? Or they'll crash the application when the limit is reached (and what happens afterward)?

Comment: Memory allocated with `new` is cleaned up when application closes/crashes no matter what it was, or when you explicitly do so using `delete`, or `deleteLater` in case `QObject` entity. It can lead to crash if memory leaks constantly - create an object via `new` and don't delete it explicitly or implicitly. Which eventually leads to out of memory, if the program will work long enough.

Comment: If I attach a `QHBoxLayout` to a `QWidget` (probably with `setLayout()`), and then delete the `QWidget`, the `QHBoxLayout` will be destroyed alongside, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. `QWidget::seLayout` as `QLayout::addWidget` sets parent for added object. In this case `QWidget::setLayout` will call something like `layout->setParent(this)`. [Source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp.html#_ZN7QWidget9setLayoutEP7QLayout).